# How do i access this: @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context from any view in my app, in swiftui?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I can only access and use this "@Environment(.managedObjectContext) var context" in my ContentView(), if i try to access "@Environment(.managedObjectContext) var context" in any other view i receive this error:
"Context in environment is not connected to a persistent store coordinator: "

How can i access it from any view in my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need in your scenedelegate.swift

```
 // Create the SwiftUI view and set the context as the value for the managedObjectContext environment keyPath.
    // Add `@Environment(\.managedObjectContext)` in the views that will need the context.
    let contentView = ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
```

And in every view

```
  @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
```

Then you can access the context in every view.

Or check out this link https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-combine-core-data-and-swiftui

Comment: i have done exactly that and i can only access the context in subviews, ex if i have a SomeView() inside the ContentView, then i can access it. But i cant access it if i try to acess it in some view that is not inside the ContentView()